# Is there a method in Gensim to find the most relevant topics between two corpuses?

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, topic-modeling

I am trying to better understand how two groups of documents relate to one another through topic modeling. I have performed similarity scoring on them and would like to try and peer deeper into how these documents relate through topic modeling. Rather than just observing the most relevant topics for each document using LDA, is there a method where I could have a model trained on both documents combined as a single corpus and visualize what topics have the most relevance to both documents combined?

I tried just running LDA on a combined corpus but it returned topics that were clearly divided in relevance between the two different underlying documents of origin. Instead, I want to see what smaller topics the two documents overlap with the most.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What you could do is to get the topics of the two groups independently and then compare the pairs of topics to find which ones are similar. The traditional way to represent topics is with their words distributions, so you could for instance compare the overlap between the top N words (since normally similar topics are supposed to have some top words in common).

Answer (score 0):

There's no one method for doing this in Gensim. But once you've trained a topic-model (such as LDA) on the combined corpus of all documents, you could do things like:

- compare any two documents, by comparing their topics
- tally top-N topics for all documents in one of the original corpuses, and then top-N topics for all documents the 2nd original corpus, then contrast those counts
- treat the original two corpuses as two giant composite documents, calculate the topics of those two synthetic documents, and compare their topics

Answer (score 0):

Gojomo's answer was pretty comprehensive.  However, if you want to do it relatively automatically, based on which words are in each topic, consider using [Cross-Source Topic Blending](https://gu-datalab.github.io/gdtm/gdtm/models/postprocessing_methods.html).  CSTB is based on the problem that given a bunch of topic sets from different data sets, can you find the overlapping topics?  It works by calculating the similarity between topics from each topic set, and can be used to find topics that overlap in all of the data sets, or just a few. For instance, by setting the `source_thresholds` to `2`, you can stipulate that a topic must be shared by any two topic sets.  Setting it higher, say, `5` if you have `5` topic sets, will be more selective, showing you on topics that are shared by all the topic sets.

You can set the `word_threshold` parameter to be how ever many words you want to topics to share (higher means that it's harder to match topics, but that the topics that are matched are more closely aligned).

Setting the `topn` parameter tells CSTB how many words per topic to consider, so that you are matching only the best words in each topic and not ones that hardly belong to a topic.